# jQuery, min-height based on browser height

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using this to set the size of a div based on the height of the browser window;

```
var height = $(window).height(); 
$(".single-block").height(height);
```

Which adds an inline height style to the `.single-block` div that matches the height of the browser window.

But what I need now is to replace the inline height style with an inline min-height style so that if there's a lot of content in one particular `.single-block` it wont spill out of the div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css().

```
var height = $(window).height(); 
$(".single-block").css("min-height", height);
```

or simply:

```
$(".single-block").css("min-height", $(window).height());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't want to use css() (as you're using jquery I can't see why you wouldn't!) you could also use style-minHeight, i.e.

```
$(".single-block").style.minHeight = height;
```

I'd use jquery myself but just thought it would be hand to display an alternative in case anyone stumbles across this question but isn't using jquery for some reason.